# Запуск консольного приложения скомпилированного для linux

Tags: c#, linux

есть скомпилированное приложение, написанное на c# под linux:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот результат сборки:

[image: результат сборки приложения]

Не знаю, что с этим делать, чтобы это запустить на linux. Кто-нибудь может подсказать?

Comment: `./server` в терминал?

Comment: `chmod +x ./server` (выставить права на запуск, один раз) потом `./server`

Comment: @aepot, а при компиляции флаг x сам не ставится?

Comment: Нет такого файла или каталога

Comment: @Qwertiy если он на виндах например собрал, а потом скопировал, то откуда?

Comment: команду надо давать на линуксах, в папке с показанными вами файлами

Comment: А как открыть терминал в папке с файлом?

Comment: @aepot, я думал, он на линуксе и собрал... Впрочем, скрин-то с виндового проводника, если приглядеться)))

Comment: давайте начнем с того, каким образом вы эти файлы на линуксовую машину скопировали? если ещё не скопировали, то ваш вопрос отличается от заданного выше. Что за линуксовая машина? Сервер где-то в сети или WSL локальный, что именно? Мы ж не будем в угадайку играть?

Comment: Написал консольное приложение клиент-сервер. То, что я хочу открыть на линуксе - это сервер, создающий хост в локальной сети, к которому можно обращаться. Скомпилировал приложение на винде, указав в параметрах linuxX64. Система линукс - Debian 10. через флешку перенёс файлы на линукс. Теперь хочу запустить, но не знаю, как.

Comment: Ну вот куда перенесли, там и запускайте как показано в самом начале. Или перенесли, а теперь файлы найти не можете? В чём именно проблема?

Comment: На линуксе все эти файлы находятся в папке Programm. Сделал, как вы написали: в терминале пишу:
chmod +x ./server -  говорит, что нет такого файла или каталога. Указал полный путь: chmod +x home/user/server - говорит, что нет такого файла или каталога снова

Comment: Ты на винде не сможешь открыть приложение скомпилированное под линукс, тебе нужно или **WSL**, или на виртуалку перенести, а в самом линуксе в терминале пишешь `cd *расположение директории с файлом*` и `./server`

Comment: "Отказано в доступе"

Comment: `home/user/server` - это не полный путь, полный путь `/home/user/server`

Comment: Перейдите точно в тот каталог, куда вы файлы скопировали, проверьте, что это тот каталог командой `pwd`. Потом проверьте какие там есть файлы командой `ls`, ну или более полная инфа `ls -la`.

Comment: Да, это та самая папка, но теперь пишет "bash: ./server - Отказано в доступе"

Comment: `csc server.cs && mono server.exe` - компиляция и запуск непосредственно на Linux. Попробуйте напустить `mono` на ваш модуль: `mono server`. Запускать из каталога, где лежит сервер.

Comment: File does not contain CIL Image